# Описать объект

Tags: другое

Здравствуйте! Пожалуйста, помогите описать мельницу. Казалось бы, что здесь сложного?
Вопрос в том, что нужно описать ее группе программистов, т.е описать ее не просто как мельницу, а еще привести какие то примеры из программирования, либо что то в этом вроде.

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

***класс Мельница***

**Конструктор объекта класса Мельница:**

количество жерновов
 - тоннаж (сколько зерна обрабатывает за 1 круг)
 - ... что-то еще

**Методы класса Мельница:**
 - один цикл переработки зерна (возвращает число кг готовой муки)
 - ... что-то еще

Примерно так.